# How to “git log -S” in JGit

Tags: jgit

i want to get the changes of a source file with the git command `git log -S'hello world'`.

It works, but I don't know how to do the same with JGit. The JGit `LogCommand` has no such option `-S`.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a quick example of how to get some log messages:

```
Git git = new Git(db);
Iterable<RevCommit> log = git.log().call();
```

**UPDATE**

Please try to  use a modified version of the JGitUtils from the great http://gitblit.com/:
Look at the source of the method `getFilesInCommit` to see how this can work (`PathChangeModel` is just used to hold the data.)

also try to read from this tutorial about `gitlog` in JGIT and dont forget to check properties of `gitlog` 
https://wiki.eclipse.org/JGit/User_Guide#LogCommand_.28git-log.29

Comment: thanks  ，i did the same as you said，but  the problem is how to support the option  '-S'

Comment: check updated answer maybe u can get something from it.